# remove duplicates by key from nested list of objects of custom dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

I have a nested list of objects called "words". It consists of objects of a class that has data like conf(float), end(float), start(float), word(string) I want to remove duplicate occuring objects which has same "word"

```
class Word:
    ''' A class representing a word from the JSON format for vosk speech recognition API '''

    def __init__(self, dict):
        '''
        Parameters:
          dict (dict) dictionary from JSON, containing:
            conf (float): degree of confidence, from 0 to 1
            end (float): end time of the pronouncing the word, in seconds
            start (float): start time of the pronouncing the word, in seconds
            word (str): recognized word
        '''

        self.conf = dict["conf"]
        self.end = dict["end"]
        self.start = dict["start"]
        self.word = dict["word"]

    def to_string(self):
        ''' Returns a string describing this instance '''
        return "{:20} from {:.2f} sec to {:.2f} sec, confidence is {:.2f}%".format(
            self.word, self.start, self.end, self.conf*100)


    def compare(self, other):
        if self.word == other.word:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I tried this but couldn't get it working

```
 nr_words = []
 c = custom_Word.Word({'conf': 0.0, 'end': 0.00, 'start': 0.00, 'word': ''}) 
 nr_words.append(c)

 for w in words:
     for nr in nr_words:
         if w.compare(nr_words[nr]):
             print("same")
         else:
             print("not same")
             nr_words.append(w.word)
             nr_words.append(w.start)
             nr_words.append(w.end)
```

here is the collection of objects
[image]

each object contain data like this

```
{'conf': 0.0, 'end': 0.00, 'start': 0.00, 'word': 'hello'} 

{'conf': 0.0, 'end': 1.00, 'start': 0.00, 'word': 'hello'} 

{'conf': 0.0, 'end': 2.00, 'start': 0.00, 'word': 'to'}
```

my compare function from the class "Word" works perfectly

```
words[0].compare(words[1])
True
```

I also tried this way

```
for i in range(0,len(words)):
    for o in range(0,len(nr_words)):
        if words[i].compare(nr_words[o]):
            print("same")
        else:
            print("not same")
            nr_words.append(w.word)
            nr_words.append(w.start)
            nr_words.append(w.end)
```

but got error "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'word'"

I am not sure whats wrong in attribute word
can some good soul guide me on how to remove the duplicate objects by "word"
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Be careful with `dict` as a parameter, as `list` or `str`, it shadows a python keyword and is not recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to:**

> exactly opposite list of what you have done now we have kept only unique word list now but repeating word list will contain words that are repeatedly seen

```py
frequency = {}

for w in words:
    if frequency.get(w.word, False):
        frequency[w.word].append(w)
    else:
        frequency[w.word] = [w]

repeated_words_list = []
for key in frequency:
    if len(frequency[key]) > 1:
        repeated_words_list.extend(frequency[key])

# 'repeated_words_list' is now a list containing
# all the Word objects whose `word` attribute
# appears 2 times or more.
```

Comment: thanks for your precious help! I tried running this but got TypeError: dict.get() takes no keyword arguments on this line "frequency[w] = frequency.get(w, default=0) + 1"

Comment: I change this line to frequency[w] = frequency.get(w.word, 1) + 1 now it runs fine but produced incorrect result few words which are not repeated at all and are present in the output

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I edited my answer (changed to `frequency.get(w, 0) + 1`)

Comment: but it still producing wrong output with (w, 0) + 1) it does not produce any output

Comment: Yeah ok I see one problem. The frequency dictionnary takes the Word objects as keys, but those are unique so I should use the word attribute of those Word objects for the keys. Answer edited and now correct (tested)

Answer (score 1):

( **First answer:**
Looking at this code, I guess `nr_words` is a list.
Could you specify what `nr_words` represents ? Is it like the list of the 'already seen' words ?

I also see that you print out `nr.word` so I suppose that `nr_words` is a list of `Word` objects.

But, the 2nd `for` loop is iterating over all the values of the `nr_words` list (`Word` objects), not its indexes.
So when you compare the two Word object on line 4, I think you should simply be using `nr` as the `other` argument for your `compare()` method, instead of `nr_words[nr]`.
)

**EDIT:**
Reply to your comment

> nr_words is an kind of empty list so that when I can compare it to dictionaries and append not repeating words in nr_words. Also I tried as you said to pass nr But got error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'word'

The error is because when the two words are not the same, you append `w.word`, `w.start` and `w.end` to the `nr_words` list (which are strings, floats and floats respectively)
Try by appending only the `Word` object like so :

**Corrected Code:**

```py
filtered_list = []

for w in words:
    already_seen = False
    for seen in filtered_list:
        # print(seen.word)
        if w.compare(seen):
            already_seen = True
    if not already_seen:
        filtered_list.append(w)

# now filtered_list is the list
# of all your words without the duplicates
# (based on the `word` attribute)
```

Comment: nr_words is an kind of empty list so that when I can compare it to dictionaries and append not repeating words in nr_words. Also I tried as you said to pass nr
But got error
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'word'

Comment: wow amazing it worked flawlessly thanks a lot, one more fever please how can I get a list only repeating words with its other attribute?

Comment: You're welcome :)
What do you mean with 'repeating words with its other attribute' ?

Comment: exactly opposite list of what you have done now we have kept only unique word list now but repeating word list will contain words that are repeatedly seen

Comment: Other attributes such as start, end, conf